# What is the purpose of using factory functions in Angular when dealing with Dependency Injection?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I came across with this code sample from https://medium.com/whozapp/use-indexeddb-with-ngrx-for-fast-angular-bootstrap-d9900f0cbc1b

```
export function accountReducerBootstrapFactory(reducer: AccountReducer) {
  // bootstrap() returns a Promise
  return () => reducer.bootstrap()
}

@NgModule({
...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      deps: [AccountReducer],
      multi: true,
      useFactory: accountReducerBootstrapFactory
    }
  ]
...
})
export class AccountModule {}
```

I don't understand why use the factory function. Couldn't I just do `useFactory: reducer.bootstrap()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/di-tips?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.tokens.ts

> Couldn't I just do useFactory: reducer.bootstrap()

No, because `useFactory` takes in a function, in your case does not return a function, but a promise. It might work if you do: `useFactory: reducer.bootstrap.bind(reducer)`.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/di-tips?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.tokens.ts) is a StackBlitz demo where I tried to experiment with DI in Angular, hopefully you'll find it useful.

---

Another use case for this is when you have an app where the client can either be a regular user or an admin and the `ApiService` must be dynamically provided, depending on the type of the client.

```js
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root',
 useFactory: userService => userService.isAdmin ? new AdminService() : new RegularUserService(),
 deps: [UserService] 
})
export abstract class ApiService { }
```